# Prompt whether to re-use an existing popout window or create a new one

Tags: javascript, browser

I should preface this with the fact that I know virtually nothing about javascript and, apart from very rare situations like this, I don't really plan on using it much. So please forgive me for not having tried to learn more about it in order to try and solve this problem for myself.

**The Situation:**

I frequently like to make use of popout browser windows. To do this I created a bookmark in my browser that contains this small piece of Javascript I copied from somewhere – I can't remember where – and adapted to suit my screen:

```
javascript:%20var%20WindowPopup%20=%20window.open(window.location.href,'PopUp','left=1150,top=830,width=660,height=410,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no');
```

**The Problem:**

As things stand, when there is an existing popout window and I select the bookmark again, the same popout window is re-used if I'm at the same site, otherwise a new popout window is created. But there are many occasions when I would like to override this default behaviour.

**Three Qustions:**

1. How can I force popouts to always open in a new window?
2. How can I force popouts to always re-use an existing window?
3. Combining the previous two options: is it possible to detect if there is an existing popout window and prompt me as to whether I want to re-use it or open a new one?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String "PopUp" in your bookmarklet is the name of your popup window. If you create another popup window using the same name, the already opened window will be reused.
If you want to get around this behavior, you will have to create a popup window with a unique name every time.

The following bookmarklet code will append a timestamp to the name of the popup window creating a unique name:

```
javascript:%20var%20WindowPopup%20=%20window.open(window.location.href,'PopUp'+Date.now(),'left=1150,top=830,width=660,height=410,scrollbars=yes,location=no,status=no');
```

This should work unless you're opening multiple popups within a millisecond.

Comment: Thanks Max. That's works great and answers my first question – which was the most important to me. Can you explain why, with my original code, a second window opens if I select the bookmark from a different site to the first? And can *that* behaviour be overridden? I'm not too fussed about the third question because I can just as easily have two separate bookmarks if necessary.

Comment: The browser probably keeps a separate list of windows for each site. Otherwise example.com could alter the content of a popup from somesite.com if they share the same popup name. This is not desired behavior. That's why the your bookmarklet produces a new window on a different site. This can not be overridden, in my opinion.

Comment: To have a prompt asking whether to create a new popup or to recycle an existing one you would have to use the `prompt` function and create a new popup name or use the previous one based on `prompt`'s return value. And you will also have to store the current popup name somewhere where it will not be overridden. It's complicated and probably a mess. Having 2 separate bookmarklets is way easier and saves you a click every time.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought that might be the case. The prompt would just have been a nicety and not re-using the same window is just a minor inconvenience, but not being able to open new windows for the same site was a real pain, so thanks again for your help and for taking the time to explain things to me.